# Problem Printing Regression Tree, "Error in cat(x, ..., sep = sep) : argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'"

Tags: r, decision-tree

I am attempting to construct a tree on some prostate cancer data.

```
> head(prostate)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  lcavol   age  lbph   lcp gleason   lpsa
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 -0.580    50 -1.39 -1.39       6 -0.431
2 -0.994    58 -1.39 -1.39       6 -0.163
3 -0.511    74 -1.39 -1.39       7 -0.163
4 -1.20     58 -1.39 -1.39       6 -0.163
5  0.751    62 -1.39 -1.39       6  0.372
6 -1.05     50 -1.39 -1.39       6  0.765
```

I declared all necessary packages and began to construct my tree.

```
> library(tree)
> pstree <- tree(lcavol ~., data=prostate, mindev=0.1, mincut=1)
> pstree <- tree(lcavol ~., data=prostate, mincut=1)
```

The commands run with no issue. However, when I try and print my tree, I encounter an error.

```
> pstree
Error in cat(x, ..., sep = sep) : 
  argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'
```

When I examine the structure of 'prostate', it shows it to be a data frame.

```
> str(prostate)
tibble [97 x 6] (S3: spec_tbl_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
```

The weirder part may be that when I plot the tree, I receive my plots as if the previous command worked

```
plot(pstree, col=8)
text(pstree, digits=2)
```

[image]

When I was loading the 'tree' package I had to update my R as I was running an older version. Could this perhaps be why I am encountering an error? Here is the version of R I am running

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          0.3                         
year           2020                        
month          10                          
day            10                          
svn rev        79318                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
nickname       Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out
```

My understanding is cat is part of the base package, so I'm not sure why this would be causing problems. Is there perhaps some other package that got removed in the update that caused this problem? I installed and loaded the package 'Cat' in case, but that did not solve it.

Also, note that this code is for a Data Mining class I am currently taking. The code and accompanying text are from Johannes Ledolter's book Data Mining and Business Analytics with R. You can see the full code for chapter 13 [Here](https://www.biz.uiowa.edu/faculty/jledolter/DataMining/rprograms.html) and the data [Here](https://www.biz.uiowa.edu/faculty/jledolter/DataMining/datatext.html). Thank you very much for your time, thought and help!

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, and did not find any other support for this online. I realised that I am getting this error when `tidyverse` and `tree` packages are both loaded simultaneously. Unloading `tidyverse` solved the problem for me.

Note: Here are the versions I am running. I made sure I am running the latest versions.

- R Studio: 1.3.1093
- R: 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
- `tree` package: 1.0.40
- `tidyverse` package: 1.0.40

Comment: Ok thank you! I ended up using the `rpart` package instead and honestly preferred it. Thanks for the comment though!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error as you when trying to call the print function of the tree class.

```
>tree_OJ
Error in cat(x, ..., sep = sep) : 
  argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'
```

The error is caused by loading package "cli", which is loaded implicitly when loading "tidyverse". The "cli" package mess up the namespace and overwrite the print function for the tree class.

```
Registered S3 method overwritten by 'cli':
  method     from
  print.tree tree
```

If you have to use the "tidyverse" package,
you can use the following code, which explicitly call the print function used for the tree class. Remember to use ":::" instead of the commonly used "::" because print.tree function is not an exposed function in the tree package.

```
tree:::print.tree(tree_OJ)
```